# Where can I find Microsoft.Sharepoint.Security lib

Tags: .net, sharepoint, tfs

Does any of you know where can I find and install this lib so can I use it in Visual Studio? I've found some SDK for Sharepoint 2013 but I cannot see this library there. I've managed to use this lib on machine where TFS server is installed but I need it in my local machine. Any ideas where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to just copy paste instructions, but it's a little too complicated to leave something out. Some of this you may have to find on the "machine where TFS server is installed" you refer to. From [How to Build Office Developer Tools Projects with TFS Team Build 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff622991.aspx) (for 2010 go [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100418072637/http:/msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff622991.aspx))

Install SharePoint Farm and Sandboxed Solution Build Support

Since SharePoint farm and sandboxed solution projects reference SharePoint Server assemblies, those SharePoint assemblies must be present on the build system.

One way to do this is to install the full version of SharePoint Server 2013 on your build system. An advantage of having SharePoint installed is that you can use it to deploy and test your SharePoint application immediately after generating the WSP file. Note, however, that SharePoint Server 2013 can degrade your system performance, and it has increased system requirements (such as requiring a 64-bit CPU).

As an alternative, you can download the required SharePoint assemblies onto your build system. For either method, you will need the proper license of SharePoint on the build system. Copy the following assemblies from the development system to the build system and put them in a Reference Assembly folder:

- Microsoft.SharePoint.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.dll
- Microsoft.Office.Server.dll
- Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.dll
- Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.Tools.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.dll
- Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.dll

These files are located in the following folder on the development system:

```
   C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI
```

It is recommended that you copy the SharePoint Server assemblies to the folder:

```
..\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\SharePoint\
```

And then add one of the following registry entries:

For 64-bit systems:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_SYSTEM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Wow6432Node\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\SharePoint15]@="<AssemblyFolderLocation>"
```

For 32-bit systems:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_SYSTEM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\ v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\SharePoint15]@="<AssemblyFolderLocation>"
```

If your SharePoint Projects refer to other SharePoint Server assemblies, copy them to the build system as well.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I can build my solution but I can't use some part of libs because of missing lib Microsoft.Sharepoint.Library.dll. Anyways most important that it can be build and published from my workstation.